# Background color of stack panel

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have stack panel in hyperlink button on button click i have to change stack panel background color

```
       <HyperlinkButton Name="WhereToStayButton" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Row="5"  Click="WhereToStayButton_Click">
              <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="sp1">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState>
                                    <Storyboard>
                   <ColorAnimation To="Green" Storyboard.TargetName="sp1"                        
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Menu/wheretostay.png"   Stretch="None"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.menu_where_stay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10" FontSize="26" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </HyperlinkButton.Template>
        </HyperlinkButton>
```

thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a Grid and bind the background property to a Brush.

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
myGrid.background = myBrush;
```